# How to get columns from dataframe into a list in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a `DataFrame` that has like 80 columns, and I need to get 12 of them into a collection, either `Array` or `List` is fine. I did google a bit and found this:

```
dataFrame.select("YOUR_COLUMN_NAME").rdd.map(r => r(0)).collect()
```

The problem is, this works for one column. If I do `df.select(col1,col2,col3...).rdd.map.collect()`, then it's giving me something like this: `Array[[col1,col2,col3]]`.

What I want is `Array[[col1],[col2],[col3]]`. Is there any way to do this in Spark?

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**

For example I have a dataframe:

```
----------
A   B   C
----------
1   2   3
4   5   6
```

I need to get the columns into this format:

```
Array[[1,4],[2,5],[3,6]]
```

Hope this is more clear...Sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can get `Array[Array[Any]]` by doing the following

```
scala> df.select("col1", "col2", "col3", "col4").rdd.map(row => (Array(row(0)), Array(row(1)), Array(row(2)), Array(row(3))))
res6: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Array[Any], Array[Any], Array[Any], Array[Any])] = MapPartitionsRDD[34] at map at <console>:32
```

`RDD` is like an `Array` so your required array is above. If you want `RDD[Array[Array[Any]]]` then you can do

```
scala> df.select("col1", "col2", "col3", "col4").rdd.map(row => Array(Array(row(0)), Array(row(1)), Array(row(2)), Array(row(3))))
res7: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Array[Array[Any]]] = MapPartitionsRDD[39] at map at <console>:32
```

You can proceed the same way for your twelve columns

**Updated**

Your updated question is more clear. So you can use `collect_list` function before you convert into an `rdd` and carry on as before.

```
scala> import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

scala> val rdd = df.select(collect_list("col1"), collect_list("col2"), collect_list("col3"), collect_list("col4")).rdd.map(row => Array(row(0), row(1), row(2), row(3)))
rdd: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Array[Any]] = MapPartitionsRDD[41] at map at <console>:36

scala> rdd.map(array => array.map(element => println(element))).collect
[Stage 11:>                                                         (0 + 0) / 2]WrappedArray(1, 1)
WrappedArray(2, 2)
WrappedArray(3, 3)
WrappedArray(4, 4)
res8: Array[Array[Unit]] = Array(Array((), (), (), ()))
```

**Dataframe only**

You can do all of these in a dataframe itself and do not need to convert to rdd

given that you have dataframe as

```
scala> df.show(false)
+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|col1|col2|col3|col4|col5|col6|
+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|1   |2   |3   |4   |5   |6   |
|1   |2   |3   |4   |5   |6   |
+----+----+----+----+----+----+
```

You can simply do the following

```
scala> import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

scala> df.select(array(collect_list("col1"), collect_list("col2"), collect_list("col3"), collect_list("col4")).as("collectedArray")).show(false)
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|collectedArray                                                                  |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|[WrappedArray(1, 1), WrappedArray(2, 2), WrappedArray(3, 3), WrappedArray(4, 4)]|
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: hmm is there any difference between the two lines...? They are both giving me RDD arrays, how do I get the array[array]?

Comment: my bad :) i pasted previous step . I have updated please check

Comment: I didn't find the update :( ? They still look both like rdd arrays to me

Comment: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Array[Any], Array[Any], Array[Any], Array[Any])] is this the array type? Also is there any method to put it into something like this: [Array[Any], Array[Any], Array[Any], Array[Any]],not inside the ()?

Comment: RDD is like array in itself as I had mentioned in my answer too. [ ] is representation of an array. By the way I have updated my answer by printing the elements. Its more evident of what I am explaining

Comment: okay. But I need to pass this "Array" into a function, when I define my function, this would be a RDD type then?

Comment: I have updated my answer :) I hope this time i got it correct

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150020/discussion-between-ramesh-maharjan-and-anna).